# 3 monitors that aren't all the same

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, gaming

If I decided to go with 3 monitors, can 1 of the 3 be different? Say I have two 27" 1080p 144hz monitors and one 27" 1440p 75hz. will this cause any problems? aside from it obviously looking funny.

Comment: Hardware recs are off-topic. That being said: how would you even see everything that happens on 1.8 meters (27") or even 2.1 m (32") of screen width?

Comment: This is more of an opinion based question.

Although, I would recommend two monitors personally.  Gaming requires a lot of attention, so having three monitors would be a little excessive.

A second monitor would definitely ease downtime or make multitasking a lot easier though.

Comment: fair enough. I have never played on anything outside of my 32" TV. Just got done building my new PC and have been using it but figured I should upgrade my Monitor. Seen a ton of ultrawide vs 3 monitor set ups , no matter what video i watch it just seems like there's to many opinions on this and I don't know which one I want yet. Sorry for anything typos , i'm tired XD

Comment: Yes, there is no rule that all of your monitors be the same size, shape, or resolution. So long as your video card can push out enough pixels to fill them you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to primarly opinion based since the answer largely depends on your own personal preferences. I'll try to state both advantage and disadvantages, but you will need to make your own choice as to what is best.

## Single large screen:

Positive:

- Very easy to setup.
- No borders between the screens.

Negative:

- Only one screen type (IPS is far superior to TN screen for everything but gaming. With only one screen you need to choose between TN (fast updates) or IPS (good colours, good viewing angle).
- Most games which go full screen will use all screen estate. That can be both good and bad (e.g. option to open a map on a second screen while playing a full screen game).

Also note that a single large screen often has a decent resolution (a.t.m. 2560x1440 and 3860 (aka 4k) are in. You need a powerful GPU to handle that.

## Multiple screen:

Positive:

- You can choose to game on 1, 2 or 3 screens (both AMD and Nvidia have options to see multiple screens as one big one). So you get more choices.
- You still have place left for notes, maps, temperature monitor apps, GPU load apps such as GPU-Z, notes etc while a game runs full screen.
- If you graphics card does not have the needed power you can scale down to 2 or 1 monitor, depending on the game.
- You can set up one screen for gaming (e.g. an expensive freesync or 144Hz screen) and one for editing pictures (IPS).

Negative:

- The obvious one: Each screen has a bezel around it. Personally I find that very distracting.
- More cables and usually more room on your computer table.

Comment: What word do you mean to use "p[rimary"?